# Loop through WP REST API AJAX Array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to loop through a AJAX array that was created from the WP REST API. I have no trouble at all returning the data from the first post in the array:

```
$( '#button' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax( {
              url: 'http://url.com/wp-json/posts?type=post&filter[posts_per_page]=20',
              success: function ( data ) {
                var post = data.shift(); // The data is an array of posts. Grab the first one.

                    $( '.item .front_feed_title' ).text( post.title );
                    $( '.item .front_feed_content' ).html( post.content );

              },
              cache: false
            } );
          } );
```

However, I need to loop through the AJAX array and I am unable to figure out the syntax that works for that. I want to pass `data` into a `.each` function This does not work:

```
$( '#button' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax( {
              url: 'http://url.com/wp-json/posts?type=post&filter[posts_per_page]=20',
              success: function ( data ) {

                 $.each([data], function(i, objects) {

                     console.log(i.title);

                 });

              },
              cache: false
            } );
          } );
```

My console says that the object is undefined. Can anyone provide some insight into how I should pass `data` into a jQuery `.each` function?

Comment: `data` is an array, so pass that. Currently you're wrapping your `data` array in another array with data as its only element `[data]`. Just pass `data`

Comment: don't downvote without telling me why

Comment: Passing `data` instead of `[data]` does not seem to make a difference in this case. It is still undefined. When I use @bassxzero answer below I do see data, but only for the first result. His almost works but does not loop through the response. Unfortunately I am unable to post the response as it contains client sensitive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your objects structure it's kind of hard to say but try.
Inside the function 'this' refers to the current object. So you can reference elements like this.KEY

```
$.each(data,function(){

console.log( this.title ,this.content);

})
```

Comment: You should explain what you're changing and why in your answer along with your code.

Comment: Why was this down voted? It's not helpful for the answerer if you don't explain...(whoever "you" are).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this out and it almost works. It displays the first result, but it does not loop through the AJAX response. Do you have any ideas why that would be? (I did not down vote you)

Comment: @mbacon40 this does loop through them all. If you only see one result then your api call only returns one result. Do you have a sample API URL?

Comment: Aha! I found that I had `var post = data.shift();` before I was running the .each. Removing this fixed the issue. Thanks!